# Creating a wavelength selectable light source using diffraction grating and broad-spectrum led

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

Could a miniature wavelength selectable light source (lamp + monochromator) be created by using a broad spectrum led or tiny xenon/deuterium lamp as a light source combined with a small diffraction grating (and other necessary optics like mirrors, lenses)? Thinking of an application in spectroscopy.